# Detect when camera is auto-focusing

Tags: ios, ios7, video-capture, autofocus

I am working on video application. I want to discard the video frames when camera is autofocusing. During autofocus image captured become blurred and image processing for that frame become bad but once autofocus is done, image processing become excellent. Any body give me solution?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/adjustingFocus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adjustingFocus` property.

Indicates whether the device is currently adjusting its focus setting. (read-only)

*Notes: You can observe changes to the value of this property using Key-value observing.

iOS 4.0 and later

---

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/adjustingFocus

Answer (score 2):

Following is a sample code in Swift 3.x.

First a observer should be added to the selected capture device at camera initialization.

```
captureDevice.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "adjustingFocus", options: [.new], context: nil)
```

Then observeValue method is overridden. By accessing the optional value returned by the method, autoFocussing frames can be identified.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    guard let key = keyPath, let changes = change else {
        return
    }

    if key == "adjustingFocus" {

        let changedValue = changes[.newKey]
        if (changedValue! as! Bool){ 
            // camera is auto-focussing
        }else{         
            // camera is not auto-focussing
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Example on Swift 4+

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    //@objc var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            self.addObservers()
        }

       func addObservers() {
             self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "captureDevice.adjustingFocus", options: .new, context: nil)

       }

       func removeObservers() {
          self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "captureDevice.adjustingFocus")
       }


      override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

         if keyPath == "captureDevice.adjustingFocus" {
             print("============== adjustingFocus: \(self.captureDevice?.lensPosition)") 
        }

    } //End of class
```

Answer (score 1):

Observing `adjustingFocus` is not working for me. It's always no. And I find this.

> Note that when traditional contrast detect auto-focus is in use, the AVCaptureDevice adjustingFocus property flips to YES when a focus is underway, and flips back to NO when it is done. When phase detect autofocus is in use, the adjustingFocus property does not flip to YES, as the phase detect method tends to focus more frequently, but in small, sometimes imperceptible amounts. You can observe the AVCaptureDevice lensPosition property to see lens movements that are driven by phase detect AF.

from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2409/_index.html)

I have not try it yet, I will try and update later.

Edit. I have try it, and confirm this's right.